# Error on retrieve() in salesforce soap api using c#

Tags: soap-api, c#

I need to retrieve records of Lead based on lead id,then I used `retrieve()` in **salesforce Soap api** and it shows error

> {"INVALID_FIELD: \nLead\n                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:17\nmalformed fieldList on retrieve"}

My sample code is

```csharp
    sObject[] Srslt=null;
    LimitInfo[] retriveleads = apiClient.retrieve(logresponse.sheader, 
           null, null, null, null,"Lead", new string[] { 
           "00Q28000002kjUyEAI" }, out Srslt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your not passing the correct parameters.. What are the fields you are querying for?

sObject[] result = connection.retrieve(string fieldList, string sObjectType, ID ids[]);

Answer (score 0):

In Soap API has retrieve() shows

```
LimitInfo[]SoapClient.retrieve(SessionHeader SessionHeader,QueryOptions QueryOptions,MruHeader MruHeader,PackageVersion[] PackageVersionHeader,string fieldList,string sObjectType,string[] ids,out sObject[] result)
```